# GUI. User input. Multi-line text box

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

A simple GUI where a user can input multiline text is needed. Here is my code how can I get the value from the form? Do I have to manually create buttons too?
I like the simplicity of [gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) module but it seems its unable to make multiline textbox? What would be the best way to get the subject done?

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
text=tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the problem with creating a button or two? You don't actually _need_ buttons, you could tell the Text widget to call a callback function whenever its contents are modified, but having a button that the user can click when they're finished makes processing simpler.

Comment: @PM2Ring Just wandering is there a thing that will put those life quality improvement buttons automatically? I just need a simple form.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's an automatic way. Of course, it's possible to build a Frame widget that contains a Text widget and a "submit" Button, and there are probably many examples of that on SO that you could borrow from.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is the answer: `text.get('1.0', 'end-1c')`?

Comment: @Nae I need a to get a multiline text from a user. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: @user2978216 What you have is the answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

like this (**Python2.7**):

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
text=Text(root)
text.pack()
gui = {}
gui["text"] = text
def keyUp(e):
    print e.keycode
    oldText = gui["text"].get(1.0,END)
    oldText = oldText[:-1] if (oldText[-1] == u"\n") else oldText
    if e.keycode in (36,104) :
        gui["text"].delete(1.0,END)
        if  ord(oldText[-1]) != 10 :
            newText = oldText + "\n"
            gui["text"].insert("1.0",newText)
        else :
            gui["text"].insert("1.0",oldText)
        gui["text"].update()


gui["text"].insert(1.0,u"Re hello\nWorld\n")

gui["text"].bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda  event: keyUp(event))
root.mainloop()
```

Suppress all new line characters on the keyboard.(i got 36(alpha),104(numlock)). Some operating systems may be able to add lines to the writing box(my big Enter Key). Ignore if the last character is a new line character `oldText = oldText[:-1] if (oldText[-1] == u"\n") else oldText`.Without forgetting, you cannot add blank lines!